# The spectrum of an invertible element $x$ is $\sigma(x^{-1})=\{\lambda^{-1}: \lambda\in \sigma(x)\}$

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras, functional-calculus

Suppose $x$ is invertible in the unital Banach algebra $A$.

How can I prove that $\sigma(x^{-1})=\{\lambda^{-1} : \lambda\in \sigma(x)\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is invertible, $x \cdot v = \lambda v$ is equivalent to $v= x^{-1}x \cdot v= \lambda x^{-1} \cdot v$, that is $x^{-1} \cdot v=\lambda^{-1} v$.

Comment: and how is $v$, because $A$ maybe is not an algebra of operators

Comment: i want to say: and who is $v$, because $A$ maybe is not an algebra of operators

Comment: This does not answer the question. Even if $A$ is an algebra of operators, the spectrum of an element of $A$ is not necessarily the set of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha\in \sigma (x^{-1})$ this means $x^{-1}-\alpha$ is not invertible. This means $\alpha\not=0$.

Suppose by way of contradiction that $x-\alpha^{-1}$ is invertible. In this case, we may find $c$ such that:

$$(x-\alpha^{-1})c=c(x-\alpha^{-1})=1\Leftrightarrow$$
$$xc=cx=1+c\alpha^{-1}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$c^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}c^{-1}=(1+c\alpha^{-1})^{-1}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$(1+c\alpha^{-1})c^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1} c^{-1}(1+c\alpha^{-1})=1\Leftrightarrow $$
$$(c^{-1}+\alpha^{-1})x^{-1}=x^{-1} (c^{-1}+\alpha^{-1})=1\Leftrightarrow $$
$$(c^{-1}+\alpha^{-1})(x^{-1}-\alpha)=(x^{-1}-\alpha) (c^{-1}+\alpha^{-1})=1-\alpha c^{-1}-1 =-\alpha c^{-1}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$(-\alpha^{-1}-c\alpha^{-2})(x^{-1}-\alpha)=(x^{-1}-\alpha)(-\alpha^{-1}-c\alpha^{-2})=1$$

But this means $x^{-1}-\alpha$ is invertible, which is a contradiction. Hence, $\alpha^{-1}\in \sigma(x)$ and we conclude that:

$$\{\alpha^{-1}\:|\: \alpha\in \sigma(x^{-1})\}\subseteq \sigma(x)$$

Reciprocally, if $\beta \in \sigma(x)$, by what we have proved (switching the roles of $x$ and $x^{-1}$), one can say $\alpha:=\beta^{-1}\in \sigma(x^{-1})$. Thus, $\beta=\alpha^{-1}$ where $\alpha \in \sigma(x^{-1})$ and we conclude:

$$\{\alpha^{-1}\:|\: \alpha\in \sigma(x^{-1})\}= \sigma(x)$$